# CSS Positioning :before :after - animated steps paragraph positioning

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-animations, positioning

I have an animated steps but I have a major problem when adding some text under each step. 
The problem is that the :before, :after line breaks when adding the paragraph

[image]
I tried different approaches:

- Absolute positioning - not good for responsive state
- Wrapping it all in ul - not displaying well
- inline and inline block positioning

I have created a class "step-paragraph"

```
        <ul class="steps">
      <li class="step step-incomplete step-active"> 
        <span class="step-icon"></span><span class="span-label">Step 1</span>
      <p class="step-paragraph">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
      </li>
      <li class="step step-incomplete step-inactive"> 
        <span class=" step-icon"></span><span class="span-label">Pass the test</span></li>
     <li class="step step-incomplete step-inactive"> 
       <span class=" step-icon"></span><span class="span-label">Start earning</span></li> 
    </ul>
```

Here's the [codepen](http://codepen.io/felixyakubov91/pen/pNPoaW) http://codepen.io/felixyakubov91/pen/pNPoaW

Any help is VERY appreciated!

Comment: What is the goal? To line up the circles with the horizontal grey line?

Comment: add display:none to step-paragraph and it shows how its supposed to be

Comment: Is this what you're after? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RoVaZJ

Comment: Yes, I did so myself on that pen. If you post it as an answer I will mark it closed

Answer (score 0):

ANSWER FOUND

```
.step-paragraph {text-align:left;margin:10px 5px;
 max-width:300px; display:inline-block;}
```

Also some :before,:after positioning